# Displaying bxslider inside an image

Tags: javascript, html, css, slide, bxslider

I have an image of a computer screen in my landing page and I want the screen to show different images as slides. Is there any way to do this using bxslider or any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have your image as a background on .bx-wrapper and use padding and the correct height and width to make the slider fit correctly